# How to use default property descriptors and successfully assign from __init__()?

Tags: python, properties, default, propertydescriptor

What's the correct idiom for this please?

I want to define an object containing properties which can (optionally) be initialized from a dict (the dict comes from JSON; it may be incomplete). Later on I may modify the properties via setters.
There are actually 13+ properties, and **I want to be able to use default getters and setters**, but that doesn't seem to work for this case:

But I don't want to have to write explicit descriptors for all of `prop1... propn`
Also, I'd like to move the default assignments out of `__init__()` and into the accessors... but then I'd need expicit descriptors.

What's the most elegant solution? (other than move all the setter calls out of `__init__()` and into a method/classmethod `_make()`?)

[DELETED COMMENT The code for badprop using default descriptor was due to comment by a previous SO user, who gave the impression it gives you a default setter. But it doesn't - the setter is undefined and it necessarily throws `AttributeError`.]

```
class DubiousPropertyExample(object):
    def __init__(self,dct=None):
        self.prop1 = 'some default'
        self.prop2 = 'other default'
        #self.badprop = 'This throws AttributeError: can\'t set attribute'
        if dct is None: dct = dict() # or use defaultdict 
        for prop,val in dct.items():
            self.__setattr__(prop,val)

    # How do I do default property descriptors? this is wrong
    #@property
    #def badprop(self): pass
    
    # Explicit descriptors for all properties - yukk
    @property
    def prop1(self): return self._prop1
    @prop1.setter
    def prop1(self,value): self._prop1 = value

    @property
    def prop2(self): return self._prop2
    @prop2.setter
    def prop2(self,value): self._prop2 = value

dub = DubiousPropertyExample({'prop2':'crashandburn'})

print dub.__dict__
# {'_prop2': 'crashandburn', '_prop1': 'some default'}
```

If you run this with line 5 `self.badprop = ...` uncommented, it fails:

```
self.badprop = 'This throws AttributeError: can\'t set attribute'
```

AttributeError: can't set attribute

[As ever, I read the SO posts on descriptors, implicit descriptors, calling them from `__init__`]

Comment: ... I'm confused. What's the issue here?

Comment: If you run this with line 5 `self.badprop = ...` uncommented, it fails since it thinks badprop is an attribute not a property. Apparently the accessors are not yet visible.

Comment: No, it fails because you haven't set a setter.

Comment: It thinks badprop is an attribute (not a descriptor, btw), but it's an attribute with no setter.

Comment: It seems like you don't need to be using properties at all. Just use regular member variables, which you initialize to their defaults then overwrite with any values from your dictionary.

Comment: @sr2222 It's a descriptor too.

Comment: Ok then. The question reduces to **'How can I write this code without explicit descriptors for all properties?'**

Comment: @smci Then your question is too vague to answer. You need to post a more representative sample, because as written the answer is "don't use properties".

Comment: Just trust me I will need properties, for future code involving those 13+ properties. Now tell me how to get implicit descriptors for them.

Comment: @Julian, technically yes, but that is confusing the point here, I think.

Comment: So then this brings us back to my original question. Creating properties dynamically is *easy*, but you need to define what you want the getters and setters to do.

Comment: @smci I think the issue is with your term "implicit descriptor". That doesn't mean anything to me, and I think the other commenters are similarly confused. (A Google search for 'python "implicit descriptor"' only returns this page.)

Comment: @Blckknight: 'how to use default descriptors', then. At least one SO user previously used the term 'implicit descriptor'.

Comment: don't use `dct={}` as a default argument ... use `dct = None` and then check for `None` and create a new dict inside the method.

Comment: @mgilson: good stylistic point (thanks) but offtopic to my question

Comment: @sr2222: that's pretty obnoxious and it's not an answer to the question **'How can I write this code without explicit descriptors for all properties?'** If the answer is *"You can't, you need 13*2 descriptors"*, then just simply say so, without the rudeness. If you have a better code idiom than writing 13*2 descriptors, show me... that sort of code isn't scalable. Hence my question.

Comment: @smci The trouble is there's no such thing as a default descriptor. You can use `@property` alone, which "defaults" to being unsettable since you haven't given a setter. If you tell us what you want the *effect* of these properties to be, we can probably tell you how to implement it. But the term "default descriptor" doesn't mean anything to us, unless it means a readonly property, which you've said isn't what you want.

Comment: I couldn't give you copy paste code unless you told me exactly what your spec is, even if I wanted to.  How do you need these properties to behave?  Do the getters/setters follow some sort of general ruleset that can be encapsulated?  Or are you just trying to jerryrig private/get/set in to Python?

Comment: There was a previous SO user who posted that you get default descriptors if you just write `@property def foo(): pass`. So he was the source of the wrong information.

Comment: When defining a property, if you don't specify a setter, deleter, or doc, you do technically get a default behavior.  The default behavior is to throw an exception, since the functionality has not been implemented.

Comment: @sr2222, I just want to get a totally plain-vanilla descriptor (read-writeable property). Without writing an explicit setter for each. If that's not possible just tell me.

Comment: @smci Python views a plain vanilla descriptor (read-writable property) as a normal attribute with the normal behaviour of attributes, and no need to write any code at all. Descriptors are a way of getting abnormal behaviour.

Comment: It is possible.  It is also pointless in almost all cases.  90% of the time, direct member access is the way to go.  9.99% of the time, you want to go with `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` as mentioned below.  The remainder are super special cases, like if for some reason you want to define default getters and setters in a base class so that you can override the behaviors in a subclass, but for some reason, you can't just directly create a property in the subclass.  I can't imagine how that would come about, but I don't rule it out.  So the question is, why do you need this functionality?

Comment: Uhuh. Please clarify how you would decide when to use direct member access, and when to redirect `__getattr__/__setattr__`?

Comment: You are going against the grain. Python is not Java. It's easy to change normal attributes to properties _when you need to_. When you have an example that actually needs a property, come back and ask how to change the regular attribute to a property. We'll be only to happy to help.

Comment: One of the prime usecases I find is when I for some reason want to store data in a member attribute rather than straight in to `__dict__`, but want it's members accessible from the object's public interface as attributes.  Like what you appear to be doing here.

Comment: @sr2222 and @gnibbler: Yes, because it's way more clear and elegant to write `x.a,x.b,x.c,x.d` than `x['a'],x['b'],x['c'],x['d']`. There will be other reasons, but I haven't written that code yet so I can't say now. Feel free to tell me yours.

Comment: That's exactly the sort of access that you get with `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`.

Comment: Aha! Thanks sr2222! So wouldn't you say the std doc does an F- job of explaining that? And almost all discussions out there on properties?

Answer (score 7):

I think you're slightly misunderstanding how properties work. There is no "default setter". It throws an `AttributeError` on setting `badprop` not because it doesn't yet know that `badprop` is a property rather than a normal attribute (if that were the case it would just set the attribute with no error, because that's now normal attributes behave), but because you haven't provided a setter for `badprop`, only a getter.

Have a look at this:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = 1


>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.foo = 2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    f.foo = 2
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

You can't set such an attribute even from outside of `__init__`, after the instance is constructed. If you *just* use `@property`, then what you have is a read-only property (effectively a method call that looks like an attribute read).

If all you're doing in your getters and setters is redirecting read/write access to an attribute of the same name but with an underscore prepended, then by **far** the simplest thing to do is get rid of the properties altogether and just use normal attributes. Python isn't Java (and even in Java I'm not convinced of the virtue of private fields with the obvious public getter/setter anyway). An attribute that is directly accessible to the outside world is a perfectly reasonable part of your "public" interface. If you later discover that you need to run some code whenever an attribute is read/written you can make it a property **then** without changing your interface (this is actually what descriptors were originally intended for, *not* so that we could start writing Java style getters/setters for every single attribute).

If you're actually doing something in the properties other than changing the name of the attribute, and you *do* want your attributes to be readonly, then your best bet is probably to treat the initialisation in `__init__` as directly setting the underlying data attributes with the underscore prepended. Then your class can be straightforwardly initialised without `AttributeErrors`, and thereafter the properties will do their thing as the attributes are read.

If you're actually doing something in the properties other than changing the name of the attribute, and you want your attributes to be readable and writable, then you'll need to actually specify what happens when you get/set them. If each attribute has independent custom behaviour, then there is no more efficient way to do this than explicitly providing a getter and a setter for each attribute.

If you're running exactly the same (or very similar) code in every single getter/setter (and it's not just adding an underscore to the real attribute name), and that's why you object to writing them all out (rightly so!), then you may be better served by implementing some of `__getattr__`, `__getattribute__`, and `__setattr__`. These allow you to redirect attribute reading/writing to the *same* code each time (with the name of the attribute as a parameter), rather than to two functions for each attribute (getting/setting).

Comment: Your comment on redirecting `__getattr__, __getattribute__, and __setattr__` instead of using properties is the issue I've been grappling with. What are the arguments against using attributes instead of properties? Is it ugly if we use a mix of attributes and properties within the same object?

Comment: @smci It's not ugly at all. In fact it's usual. In fact it's **necessary**. After all, your properties were trying to redirect `prop1` to `_prop1`, and `_prop1` is a normal attribute. If a given property needs to have the behaviour of being writable, and having a read retrieve the last written value, with no other customisations, then the simplest and most direct way to implement that is to have it be an attribute. If another property on the same object needs to have custom behaviour, then you make that one a property.

Comment: properties are special objects attached as member attributes to a class that under the covers implement the descriptor protocol to override the default member access mechanism.  Properties are generally for when a specific member requires special access rules.  `__getattr__`/`__setattr__` are when you need special behavior in a systematic, instance-wide way.

Comment: @smci The entire **point** of descriptors is to obscure the distinction between the the two cases, so you can switch your implementation back and forth between the two without breaking your interface.

Comment: Ok, I formed the mistaken impression from many readings of the doc that a) properties were 'better' than attributes in some undefined way (like say for stability when iterating over obj.__dict__) and b) that properties and attributes should not be freely mixed - evidently my impression was wrong. Gotta say [Ben's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/450128/ben) comment is way clearer than the std doc. Thanks.

Comment: properties are just class attributes.  When you try to access an attribute on an instance, the interpreter walks the MRO (instance, instance's class, instance's class' parents, etc) until it finds an object that does not raise an AttributeError for that name.  If the returned value implements the descriptor protocol, it calls the `__set__` or `__get__` as appropriate, otherwise it just directly operates on the reference provided.  The docs on properties and `__getattr__` \ `__setattr__` don't really cover each other because each is out of scope of the other except for advanced usecases.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the easiest way to go about this is to just implement `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` such that they will access any key in your parsed JSON dict, which you should set as an instance member.  Alternatively, you could call `update()` on `self.__dict__` with your parsed JSON, but that's not really the best way to go about things, as it means your input dict could potentially trample members of your instance.

As to your setters and getters, you should only be creating them if they actually do something special other than directly set or retrieve the value in question.  Python isn't Java (or C++ or anything else), you shouldn't try to mimic the private/set/get paradigm that is common in those languages.

Answer (score 0):

I simply put the dict in the local scope and get/set there my properties.

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        #self.value = 20 asign from init is possible
    @property
    def value(self):
        if self.kwargs.get('value') == None:
            self.kwargs.update(value=0)#default
        return self.kwargs.get('value')
    @value.setter
    def value(self,v):
        print(v) #do something with v
        self.kwargs.update(value=v)

x = test()
print(x.value)
x.value = 10
x.value = 5
```

---

**Output**

```
0
10
5
```